# Charging capacitor with a diode in parallel

Tags: capacitor, resistors, diodes, analog

Suppose we have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL0JiQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we didnt have the diode , we could use **source transformation** to calculate the charging time of the capacitor just like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwKUrs.png)</sup>

but now we have the diode I cannot do this.How is the charging time calculated?

Comment: How accurately do you need to model the diode's behavior? What are you assuming about the diode?

Comment: Saturation current 10-12A , ideality factor =1

Comment: You need to run SPICE on this. Don't bother trying to solve it on paper.

Comment: The max voltage on C1 will be limited to \$Vf\$ of the diode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially you can ignore the diode, but once the voltage across the resistor and the capacitor reaches the forward voltage drop of the diode, Vf, it will be effectively clamped and all the current will be shared by the diode and the resistor. No further charging of the capacitor will occur. So run the simulation without the diode and draw a line where the voltage reaches Vf, typically 0.7V for an ordinary silicon diode. There will be the slight inaccuracy due to the I/V characteristic of the diode not being a perfect right angle knee.